# How to retrieve data from a json array

Tags: android, json, parsing

this is how my json response looks like

```
{
    "id": "fe4a69ef-8b8b-42ad-9c5c-9e0c3e449441",
    "createTime": "2014-04-09T11:29:26Z",
    "updateTime": "2014-04-09T11:29:26Z",
    "status": "Created",
    "transaction": {
        "amount": {
            "currencyCode": "GPP",
            "total": 122
        },
        "qrcode": "1f0e3dad99908345f7439f8ffabdfiop",
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
}
```

when I try to extract values from each parameter upto status I could extract it but when I try to extract the currencyCode it shows **`No value for currencyCode`**

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) post and modified my code but no use yet

my code

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(toReturn);

         if(jObject.has("error")){               
             RES_STATUS     =   AppConstants.FAIL;
         }
         else{               
             AppVariables.id                    =   jObject.getString(AppVariables.id_);
             AppVariables.createTime            =   jObject.getString(AppVariables.createTime_);
             AppVariables.updateTime            =   jObject.getString(AppVariables.updateTime_);
             AppVariables.status                =   jObject.getString(AppVariables.status_);
             JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("transaction");


             for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
             {
                 try {
                     JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     // Pulling items from the array
                     String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("total");
                     String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("currencyCode");
                     Log.e("oneObjectsItem", oneObjectsItem);
                     Log.e("oneObjectsItem2", oneObjectsItem2);
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // Oops
                     Log.e("OOps", e.toString());
                 }
             }


             AppVariables.total                 =   String.valueOf(jObject.getInt(AppVariables.total_));
             AppVariables.qrcode                =   jObject.getString(AppVariables.qrcode_);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
"transaction": {        //this is JSONObject not array
```

Remove below lines

```
         JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("transaction");
         for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
         {
             try {
                 JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 // Pulling items from the array
                 String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("total");
                 String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("currencyCode");
                 Log.e("oneObjectsItem", oneObjectsItem);
                 Log.e("oneObjectsItem2", oneObjectsItem2);
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 // Oops
                 Log.e("OOps", e.toString());
             }
         }
```

And add below lines

```
        JSONObject transaction_obj = jObject.getJSONObject("transaction");
        JSONObject oneObject = transaction_obj.getJSONObject("amount");
        String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("total");
        String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("currencyCode");
        Log.e("oneObjectsItem", oneObjectsItem);
        Log.e("oneObjectsItem2", oneObjectsItem2);
        AppVariables.qrcode = transaction_ob.getString("qrcode");
```

Comment: It worked but now am getting No value for total. I tried 

AppVariables.total=jObject.getJSONObject("total").toString();

AppVariables.qrcode=jObject.getJSONObject(AppVariables.qrcode_).toString(); 

but doesnt seems to work

Comment: @suja you have to get like `AppVariables.total=jObject.getString("total"))`.

Answer (score 0):

[gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is another perfect solution for json resolving.

Answer (score 0):

transaction is not an JsonArray. That is JsonObject.Try following code. I hope this will help you

```
JSONObject objTransaction= jObject.getJSONObject("transaction");
String strQrcode=objTransaction.getString("qrcode");
String strDescription=objTransaction.getString("description");
JSonObject objAmount=objTransaction.getJSONObject("amount");

String strTotal=objAmount.getString("total");
String strCurrencyCode = objAmount.getString("currencyCode");
```